# input type=email failing validation over 72 characters

Tags: html, email

On testing an HTML form with a email input text box, I'm noticing that any email address over 72 characters fails validation: "Please enter an email address" in both Chrome and Firefox.  I didn't realize the validation for input type=email limited to 72 characters, and can't find any documentation about it, W3C or otherwise:

```html
<input type="email" style="width:800px" maxlength="100" />
```

Comment: I'm unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/1vapLLfv/  Can you give an example of an email address that fails?  (But change the domain for privacy.)

Comment: Yup. This works as intended. No error-messages for "valid" email-addresses. So your example isn't complete - there is something else causing an error, not the code you posted above.

Comment: same here it seems to work , i am able to enter 100 characters into the input field no problem.

Comment: if you have an email that long it's quite possible that you just mistyped, or added a space somewhere.

Comment: Interesting, there is no error for the default value in that fiddle of 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890@example.com, but the value I've been testing with does fail: test@testtttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt.com whether you put the long string of t's before of after the @ symbol

Comment: That's longer than 100 characters, but I *can* confirm that it fails even if you reduce it to 100 characters.  So it's an issue with the domain part of the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [**RFC1035**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) - Domain Names - Implementation and Specification, here is the syntax:

> <domain> ::=  | " "
>
> <subdomain> ::= <label> | <subdomain> "." <label>
>
> <label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]
>
> <ldh-str> ::= <let-dig-hyp> | <let-dig-hyp> <ldh-str>
>
> <let-dig-hyp> ::= <let-dig> | "-"
>
> <let-dig> ::= <letter> | <digit>
>
> <letter> ::= any one of the 52 alphabetic characters A through Z in
> upper case and a through z in lower case
>
> <digit> ::= any one of the ten digits 0 through 9

Note that:

> Labels must be 63 characters or less.

The example domain name in your comment is greater than 63 characters, hence the failure to validate.